# docx format opened simultaneously with LO writer and Kingsoft writer

Tags: libreoffice, mime-type, file-type, word-documents, word-processor

im using ubuntu raring 64 bit now, i just downloaded kingsoft office for i686 arhcitecture, unfortunantely it seemed that i downloaded it wrongly (i downloaded the 32 bit rpm version!) and forced to install it by using alien (let say the package name is kingsoft64.rpm) this way:

```
alien --to-tgz Kingsoft64.rpm
```

Then i extract the tgz file generated by code above (ex. Kingsoft64.tgz which resulted a directory named Kingsoft (not the real folder name) ), then i did this:

```
> me@mycomp:$cd ~/Kingsoft
> me@mycomp:~/Kingsoft$ ls
> install opt usr
```

I copy the **opt** and **usr** folder and merge it to /opt and /usr folder in my root directory,
the last thing i did was executing doinstall.sh which is located at ~/KIngsoft/install, The doinstall.sh contain following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/update-mime-database /usr/share/mime &> /dev/null || :
/usr/bin/update-desktop-database &> /dev/null || :
/bin/touch --no-create /usr/share/icons/hicolor &>/dev/null || :
if [ -x /usr/bin/fc-cache ]; then 
    /usr/bin/fc-cache /usr/share/fonts/wps-office || : 
fi
```

The Kingsoft office writer can be ran correctly by running from terminal with:

```
wps
```

and the Kingsoft office presentation tool was also can be ran correctly with:

```
wpp
```

The only problem is, the docx file asscociation is likely to be shared with Libre Office 4.1 (installed previously on my system) and with Kingsoft office, so when i try to double clicked a .docx document, LO and Kingsoft Office were ran together simultaneously to open the .docx file,

How can i get rid the .docx file association from LO to make sure when i click .docx document it only opened with Kingsoft office and not opened together with LO?
Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open .docx with Kingsoft Writer as default, just right click on the .docx file, and click on properties.  Once the properties window open, click on the open with tab, choose Kingsoft witer, and click on Set as Default.  See images below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Completely worked!
But another question,
if I want to know where do the mime type configration files are, and how to config or asscociate it with some application, where should I start?

Comment: Take a look at `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`